# Django - How to differentiate between users in the database?

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I'm building a Django server for my company and I'm still unfamiliar with some processes. I'm sure this is super simple, I'm just completely unaware of how this works.

How do I differentiate between user's data so it doesn't get mixed up?

If Jill is a user and she requests a page of her profile data, how do I not send her Jack's profile data, especially if there are multiple models invovled?

For example, the code in the view would look like this:

```
def display_profile(request)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(???) # What do I put in here?
```

I understand that I can do:

```
def display_profile(request, user)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user)
```

But that's not my design intention.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"that's not my design intention"_: What is your design intention? What is wrong with that approach?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

> Django uses sessions and middleware to hook the authentication system into request objects.

> These provide a request.user attribute on every request which
> represents the current user. If the current user has not logged in,
> this attribute will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser, otherwise
> it will be an instance of User.

So in your case (notice field not being called user_id )

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Django view, you can access the current user with `request.user`.

So if you want to get a Profile instance matching your current logged in user, just do a query as follow:

```py
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

This assumes you have a `user` foreign key field (or OneToOne) in your Profile model.